# How to parse a XLS file in python which contains HTML code?

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas, parsing

I have downloaded a dataset which gives you .XLS files but when I open it using the notepad I see HTML tags/code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Monthly Volume Report NRA 000000001508 2019-08-01 to 2019-08-31</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
.key td { white-space: nowrap; }
.key td.A,.key td.W,.key td.S,.key td.C,.key td.H { white-space: pre; }
td.A { background-color: #DD9CB3; } /* Salmon */
td.W { background-color: #80F7B5; } /* SeaGreen */
td.S { background-color: #FFFF80; } /* Yellow */
td.C { background-color: #A6CAF0; } /* Blue */
td.H { background-color: #CCCCCC; } /* Weekend grey */
td.WeA { background-color: #99586F; }
td.WeW { background-color: #3CB371; }
td.WeS { background-color: #CCCC40; }
td.WeC { background-color: #6286AC; }
td.WeH { background-color: #CCCCCC; }
td.We,th.We { background-color: #CCCCCC; }
td.P { border: 1px solid #808080; } /* Patched - border */
td.TLI { color:#A0A0A0; } /* Too Little Information - grey text */
td.NOI { color:red; } /* Too Little Information - red text */
.grid td { border:none; } /* No borders by default */
.grid .TBL td, .grid .TBL { border-left:2px solid #000000; } /* Thick left border for intermediate totals */
.grid .TBR td, .grid .TBR { border-right:2px solid #000000; } /* Thick right border for intermediate totals */
.grid .TBT td, .grid .TBT { border-top:2px solid #000000; } /* Thick top border for intermediate totals */
.grid .TBB td, .grid .TBB { border-bottom:2px solid #000000; } /* Thick bottom border for intermediate totals */
.grid .BL td, .grid .BL { border-left:1px solid #000000; } /* Thin left border for intermediate totals */
.grid .BR td, .grid .BR { border-right:1px solid #000000; } /* Thin right border for intermediate totals */
.grid .BT td, .grid .BT { border-top:1px solid #000000; } /* Thin top border for intermediate totals */
.grid .BB td, .grid .BB { border-bottom:1px solid #000000; } /* Thin bottom border for intermediate totals */
.grid .TBP th, .grid .TBP { padding-top: 1.5ex; padding-bottom: 1.5ex; mso-ignore: padding; } /* Top and bottom padding */
th { mso-number-format: \@; } /* So dates in headers are interpreted as strings */
th.XlDM { mso-number-format:"d mmm"; } /* Force short dates */
th.WeXlDM { background-color: #CCCCCC; mso-number-format:"d mmm"; } /* Force short dates */
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body class="fixed">
<div id="wrapper">
<b>Monthly Volume Report NRA 000000001508 2019-08-01 to 2019-08-31</b> <div id="container">
  <div id="content">
<div class="panel panel-default">  <div class="panel-heading">   <table>
    <tr><td>Site Name</td><td style='mso-number-format:"\@";' colspan=3>TMU M50 015.0 S </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Site ID</td><td style='mso-number-format:"\@";' colspan=3>000000001508</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Grid</td><td style='mso-number-format:"\@";' colspan=3>308164236836</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Description</td><td colspan=3>M50 Between Jn06 N03/M50 and Jn07 N04/M50, Castleknock, Co. Dublin</td></tr>
   </table>
</div>  <div class="panel-body">   <div id="selector">
    <ul id="dropdownmenu">
<table><tr><td>Setup</td><td colspan=3>M50 1508</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Channel</td><td colspan=3>Each Direction
</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Time Period</td><td colspan=3>1 hour
</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Class</td><td colspan=3>Any</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Exclude data:</td><td colspan=3>None</td></tr></table>
    </ul>
   </div> <!--selector-->
<table class="grid" id="gridTable" BORDER=1>
 <tr><th style="text-align:left; font-size:110%;" colspan=35>All directions</th></tr>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <th class="We">Sat</th>
  <th class="We">Sun</th>
  <th class="We">Mon</th>
  <th>Tue</th>
  <th>Wed</th>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <th class="We">Sat</th>
  <th class="We">Sun</th>
  <th>Mon</th>
  <th>Tue</th>
  <th>Wed</th>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <th class="We">Sat</th>
  <th class="We">Sun</th>
  <th>Mon</th>
  <th>Tue</th>
  <th>Wed</th>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <th class="We">Sat</th>
  <th class="We">Sun</th>
  <th>Mon</th>
  <th>Tue</th>
  <th>Wed</th>
  <th>Thu</th>
  <th>Fri</th>
  <th class="We">Sat</th>
  <th colspan=2>Average</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="BP">
  <th></th>
  <th>2019-08-01</th>
  <th>2019-08-02</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-03</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-04</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-05</th>
  <th>2019-08-06</th>
  <th>2019-08-07</th>
  <th>2019-08-08</th>
  <th>2019-08-09</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-10</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-11</th>
  <th>2019-08-12</th>
  <th>2019-08-13</th>
  <th>2019-08-14</th>
  <th>2019-08-15</th>
  <th>2019-08-16</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-17</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-18</th>
  <th>2019-08-19</th>
  <th>2019-08-20</th>
  <th>2019-08-21</th>
  <th>2019-08-22</th>
  <th>2019-08-23</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-24</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-25</th>
  <th>2019-08-26</th>
  <th>2019-08-27</th>
  <th>2019-08-28</th>
  <th>2019-08-29</th>
  <th>2019-08-30</th>
  <th class="We">2019-08-31</th>
  <th>Workday</th>
  <th>7 Day</th>
  <th>Count</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="T">
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>00:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">1535</td>
  <td class="S">1549</td>
  <td class="WeS">1673</td>
  <td class="WeS">1536</td>
  <td class="WeS">1437</td>
  <td class="S">1410</td>
  <td>1326</td>
  <td>1492</td>
  <td>1612</td>
  <td class="We">1904</td>
  <td class="We">1705</td>
  <td>1389</td>
  <td>1410</td>
  <td>1386</td>
  <td>1600</td>
  <td>1476</td>
  <td class="We">1957</td>
  <td class="We">1792</td>
  <td>1346</td>
  <td>1437</td>
  <td>1465</td>
  <td>1594</td>
  <td>1625</td>
  <td class="We">1871</td>
  <td class="We">1737</td>
  <td>1449</td>
  <td>1349</td>
  <td>1462</td>
  <td>1358</td>
  <td>1489</td>
  <td class="We">1749</td>
  <td>1463</td>
  <td>1551</td>
  <td>48120</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>01:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">1096</td>
  <td class="S">1076</td>
  <td class="WeS">1262</td>
  <td class="WeS">1194</td>
  <td class="WeS">1042</td>
  <td class="S">846</td>
  <td>926</td>
  <td>948</td>
  <td>1102</td>
  <td class="We">1282</td>
  <td class="We">1190</td>
  <td>891</td>
  <td>984</td>
  <td>869</td>
  <td>1002</td>
  <td>1095</td>
  <td class="We">1080</td>
  <td class="We">1344</td>
  <td>948</td>
  <td>952</td>
  <td>904</td>
  <td>983</td>
  <td>1121</td>
  <td class="We">1083</td>
  <td class="We">1333</td>
  <td>757</td>
  <td>864</td>
  <td>868</td>
  <td>889</td>
  <td>1005</td>
  <td class="We">1103</td>
  <td>962</td>
  <td>1032</td>
  <td>32039</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>02:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">591</td>
  <td class="S">759</td>
  <td class="WeS">776</td>
  <td class="WeS">851</td>
  <td class="WeS">706</td>
  <td class="S">567</td>
  <td>652</td>
  <td>674</td>
  <td>758</td>
  <td class="We">1007</td>
  <td class="We">836</td>
  <td>507</td>
  <td>801</td>
  <td>623</td>
  <td>638</td>
  <td>726</td>
  <td class="We">844</td>
  <td class="We">812</td>
  <td>538</td>
  <td>677</td>
  <td>620</td>
  <td>688</td>
  <td>720</td>
  <td class="We">733</td>
  <td class="We">843</td>
  <td>518</td>
  <td>593</td>
  <td>666</td>
  <td>664</td>
  <td>675</td>
  <td class="We">809</td>
  <td>653</td>
  <td>705</td>
  <td>21872</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="T">
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>03:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">787</td>
  <td class="S">979</td>
  <td class="WeS">831</td>
  <td class="WeS">844</td>
  <td class="WeS">788</td>
  <td class="S">781</td>
  <td>831</td>
  <td>817</td>
  <td>974</td>
  <td class="We">947</td>
  <td class="We">886</td>
  <td>868</td>
  <td>763</td>
  <td>802</td>
  <td>762</td>
  <td>904</td>
  <td class="We">882</td>
  <td class="We">863</td>
  <td>828</td>
  <td>772</td>
  <td>745</td>
  <td>798</td>
  <td>905</td>
  <td class="We">854</td>
  <td class="We">796</td>
  <td>837</td>
  <td>740</td>
  <td>740</td>
  <td>727</td>
  <td>881</td>
  <td class="We">896</td>
  <td>819</td>
  <td>833</td>
  <td>25828</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>04:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">1356</td>
  <td class="S">1449</td>
  <td class="WeS">1318</td>
  <td class="WeS">1133</td>
  <td class="WeS">1200</td>
  <td class="S">1432</td>
  <td>1351</td>
  <td>1321</td>
  <td>1637</td>
  <td class="We">1287</td>
  <td class="We">1117</td>
  <td>1448</td>
  <td>1358</td>
  <td>1342</td>
  <td>1337</td>
  <td>1389</td>
  <td class="We">1348</td>
  <td class="We">1064</td>
  <td>1367</td>
  <td>1408</td>
  <td>1447</td>
  <td>1346</td>
  <td>1538</td>
  <td class="We">1275</td>
  <td class="We">1048</td>
  <td>1317</td>
  <td>1391</td>
  <td>1196</td>
  <td>1394</td>
  <td>1498</td>
  <td class="We">1375</td>
  <td>1387</td>
  <td>1339</td>
  <td>41487</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="RHR" style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>05:00:00</td>
  <td class="S">2516</td>
  <td class="S">2444</td>
  <td class="WeS">1659</td>
  <td class="WeS">1136</td>
  <td class="WeS">1512</td>
  <td class="S">2609</td>
  <td>2518</td>
  <td>2490</td>
  <td>2466</td>
  <td class="We">1608</td>
  <td class="We">1203</td>
  <td>2651</td>
  <td>2554</td>
  <td>2441</td>
  <td>2441</td>
  <td>2419</td>
  <td class="We">1628</td>
  <td class="We">1254</td>
  <td>2676</td>
  <td>2528</td>
  <td>2496</td>
  <td>2443</td>
  <td>2452</td>
```

Here is how it looks in when opened in excel

[image]

So my question is how do I read this table which is being displayed in excel through python. When I tried to parse it through read XLS function in pandas it threw me errors

edit: the entire contents of XLS file can be found here on pastebin

https://pastebin.com/2rpyAZhE

Comment: `pandas.read_html` can handle html but you have multiple data sets in this file in different formats (e.g., time is a row until it switches to "am peak" where time is a column). I think you'll need to trim down the html to the data you want and  then import. You could use one of the python xml parsers perhaps with XPATH or even an XSL (extended stylesheet) to pull out what you want.

Comment: Which part of the data are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to open the file in Excel and save it in .xlsx format. You could read it directly into a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('2rpyAZhE.xlsx')
```

Another option would be to use BeautifulSoup. Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('2rpyAZhE.html', 'r'), "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table', {"class": "grid"})
df = pd.read_html(str(table[0]))[0]
```

Because the source is quite messy (merged cells, empty rows, etc.), you might want to do some preprocessing on it to clean it up a bit / be more selective with the beautiful soup search, before reading it into a dataframe.

Comment: You should use a context manager for the file in the second example.