# Python Pandas can't read .xls file though engine is xlrd

Tags: python, pandas, xls, xlrd

have a 1 GB excel sheet with xls format (old excel), and I can't read it with pandas

`df = pd.read_excel("filelocation/filename.xls",engine = "xlrd")`

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<html>\r\n'
```

and if removed the engine it sends this error

```
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually
```

any advice will be appreciated thanks

Comment: That's not an Excel sheet you're trying to read, it's an HTML file. Or maybe a corrupt XLS with bits of HTML in it.

Comment: thank you, first time to deal with that, any idea how to make it into a decent table / get the table inside the file, when I read_table it gives to columns with buch of HTML tags?!

Comment: What prints when you do `print(open("filelocation/filename.xls").read()[:200])`?

Comment: bunch of html and css tags, but I can see that there is a table in the file, but can't get it !

Comment: I think you're in the same situation as this [How to parse a XLS file in python which contains HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60142448/how-to-parse-a-xls-file-in-python-which-contains-html-code). I think [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) may work. See also [I can't seem to open an .xls format file from Salesforce printable view in Mac Numbers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18771/i-cant-seem-to-open-an-xls-format-file-from-salesforce-printable-view-in-mac-n) showing html can masquerade as xls sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of these options should work:

```
data = pandas.read_table(r"filelocation/filename.xls")
```

or

```
data = pandas.read_html("filelocation/filename.xls")
```

Otherwise, try another HTML parse, I agree with @AKX, this doesn't look like an excel file.

Comment: The last one is the savior for me! 
I've tried so many things, didn't work for me.